# How to add a function that finds largest and smallest values and displays them

Tags: c#

I made a program that asks you to enter a few numbers less than 100, and then takes the numbers you entered and tells you which ones were valid entries. What I want to add is a feature that takes those valid entries and finds the smallest and largest numbers. After it finds the smallest and largest values I want them to be displayed under where it says "Invalid entries:." Can anyone help me with adding this?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Programming_Exercise_2_Chapter_6
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string answer;
                do
                {      
                    Console.Clear();
                    Header();
                    int number;
                    string indata;
                    List<int> validEntries = new List<int>();
                    List<string> invalidEntries = new List<string>();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Insert numbers less than 100: ");
                        indata = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (Int32.TryParse(indata, out number))
                        {
                            if (number <= 100 && number > 0)
                                validEntries.Add(number);

                             else
                                invalidEntries.Add(number.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                            invalidEntries.Add(indata);

                        Console.WriteLine("Press N to stop. Press enter to continue.");
                        indata = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Clear();

                        if (indata == "n"|| indata == "N")
                            break;
                    }            
                    DisplayEntries(validEntries, invalidEntries);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to try again?(Enter Y for Yes, or N for       No)");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                while (answer == "Y" || answer == "y");
            }
            static void DisplayEntries(List<int> validEntries, List<string> invalidEntries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your valid entries were: ");
                foreach (int i in validEntries)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Your invalid entries were: ");
                foreach (string s in invalidEntries)
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            static void Header()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tNumber Validation App");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a few numbers less than 100.\nValid entries     will be displayed.");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be specific. You are (one assumes) asking for help with code you have been unable to get work, and not asking simply for someone to write the code for you. So instead of showing all the UI code (which is irrelevant), show the code that takes your input and tries to find the values you want. Explain what you've done, what the output is, and why that's different from what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details

Comment: No need to post  entire code here . Better post  a method !!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to have the smallest and largest entry from your integer list?
In that case you can simply sort the list and retrieve the first / last entry of the sorted list:

```
validEntries.Sort();
var smallest = validEntries.First();
var highest = validEntries.Last();
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of integers(numbers). ranging between 1 and 100. all of the stored in validEntries.
So you have to go through all numbers in the list, when you find a high one you store it and compare it to the next number in the list.

```
int highest_nr = 0;
int lowest_nr  = 100;
foreach (int i in validEntries)
{
    if (i < lowest_nr)
        lowest_nr = i
    if (i > highest_nr)
        highest_nr = i;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.WriteLine("Highest number = " + highest_nr.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Lowest number  = " + lowest_nr.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`validEntries.Max()` and `validEntries.Min()` will get you your highest and lowest values, respectively.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Your valid entries were: ");
        foreach (int i in validEntries)
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Your invalid entries were: ");
        foreach (string s in invalidEntries)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Would be written (I replaced your foreach):

```
            Console.WriteLine("Your valid entries were: ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validEntries));

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your invalid entries were: ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, invalidEntries));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Min:{0}  Max:{1}",validEntries.Min(),validEntries.Max());
```